# How to retrieve html from web pages generated on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

2 years back I shelved a working Ruby web **scraper** that automatically download TV movie listings for a 1 week period at a time.  Started to work on it again today and found that Ruby can neither access the controls or data of the web page being displayed.

Debugging shows that scripts are now generating the documents that load subsequent web pages. Also the initial scripts modify the current document when run (remove links). Any url used results in the same initial web page being loaded.

I am looking for suggestions on how to proceed to access the data in displayed web pages. I am not very knowledgeable about javascript but would pursue if I had a definite plan to follow.  I believe I found the href to load the second web page but it only loads the initial page again so other mechanisms are in play (ie there are cookies mentioned in the script).

To download the information there are minimum of 28 web pages required and normally with downloading movie information there are several hundred web pages processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered you can't scrape webpages with dynamic content with simple HTTP requests. You need to simulate the webpage actually being used in order for the Javascript to run and generate the content you need. This [tutorial](https://gustavocguimaraes.wordpress.com/2016/01/18/web-scraping-ajax-heavy-page-with-ruby/) will probably help you do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.